# REACT: TypeError e.preventDefault is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I would like to prevent the page from refreshing after submitting this form and am unable to do so. To solve this issue, so far I've tried adding a `return false` statement at the end of the function but that didn't prevent submission. If I comment out everything after e.preventDefault(), it runs successfully.

JS:

```
async function postQuestion(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        const requestBody = {
            "Subject": vidTimeMins.current.value + ":" + vidTimeSecs.current.value,
            "Message": {
                "Content": textBox.current.value,
                "Type": "Text"
            },
        }
        const res = await postQuestion(requestBody)
        console.log(res)
    }
```

Corresponding HTML:

```
<Button variant="secondary" type="submit" onClick={postQuestion}>Post Question</Button>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If not mistaken you should pass the event in the call (onClick).

Comment: I tried `onClick={(e) => postQuestion(e)}` but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Why you are doing a recursive by calling the same function inside, maybe that what causing you an issue.

Comment: That was causing the issue. Thanks!